# How to merge multiple json objects into one by key? (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

I am getting an array from json objects, but I want to get one object that will have many keys and values.

```
select 
    t1.column1, 
    jsonb_agg(t2.column2) 
from table t1
left join table t2
group by column1
```

I have -
`[{"0001": 75.00, "0002": 60.00}, {"0001": 50.00}]`

I want -
`{"0001": 50.00, "0002": 60.00}`

I found an example like this, but I can't figure out how to apply it to my example.

```
with name as (
  select '{"1": 5, "2": 53}'::jsonb as val  union
  select '{"1": 74, "2": 34, "3": 54}'::jsonb as val
)
select jsonb_object_agg(jv.key, jv.value order by jv.value asc) as merged_object from name
left join jsonb_each(column) jv on true;
```

Help me please

Comment: Hi Sanya, why does is the "0001":50.00 in your result? What's the aggregation method in case of the same key?

Answer (score 1):

You have to take apart the JSONs and re-assemble them:

```
select 
    t1.column1, 
    jsonb_object_agg(t3.key, t3.value) 
FROM t1
   LEFT JOIN t2 ON something
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(t2.column2) AS t3
GROUP BY t1.column1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided the question like this

```
jsonb_object_agg(coalesce(cl.key, '0'), cl.value order by cl.value desc)
...
left join jsonb_each(column) cl on true
```